# ExtendedSocketException thrown at run time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I have a project developed in C# using Visual Studio for mac. Unfortunately it works fine sometimes & failed sometimes. The code and the exception as follows.
How can I resolve this?

```
public static class ServerSettings
{
    public static string Version = "xxx";
    public static string[] IpAddresses
    {
        get
        {
            var hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            var ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
            return ipHostEntry.AddressList
                .Where(a => a.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                .Select(a => a.ToString())
                .ToArray();
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Console Log: 
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException' in System.Net.NameResolution.dll
If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: Can you try something like "var hostName = Dns.GetHostName() + ".local";  Its worth a shot, though might not work. Macs use mdns. If you google you can find some libraries. I has a similar (opposite direction) problem trying to discover a wifi enabled device that used mdns.

Comment: @Wolf-Kun it will not work, because in the next line it gives syntax error

Comment: Hm. I highly suspect the problem is with the .net dns class. It works with windows host names and regular DNS, but not with MDNS or bonjour.   Maybe this can help 'https://www.codeproject.com/questions/798321/how-to-fetch-ip-subnet-gateway-preferred-and-alter'. its in vb, but should be easy enough to convert to c#. The idea is that the networkinterface class can be used to get your ip address directly. The way you are trying is looking up your computer via DNS. That will work for windows or if you have a registered DNS, but may not work with mac.

Comment: Actually I have another Mac which has Catalina OS. It works fine without any errors. Big Sur have the problem.

Comment: Both machines have different .NET core versions. Is it a problem?

Comment: I would definitely update the non-working one to match the working one as it could have been a bug fixed. Also, could it be the mac version? is the other mac older OS? I would check both in case.

Comment: Older OS version (.net core 3) works fine. New OS version (.net core 5) caused the problem. should I downgrade and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case inside the machine name there were Japanese characters(something like **MMKのMacBook**) which caused the problem.
This may be a stupid answer but, after removing those Japanese characters I could able to manage the successful connection with the server. 
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the null condition in the IP host entry and address list might be data not available sometimes and gives to error

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I know it happens because of no any data getting by DNS. I want to get that IP address list.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is it possible we will get your remote and check your issue then may be I will try to resolve it?

Comment: sorry, remote access cannot be granted.

Comment: Also, it's possible sometimes the network is not available or specific IP not available in the network. Because I've also faced the same type of issue. Please first check in cmd. Let me know if any other concerns.

Comment: Also, maintain log file for checking issue